# Django doesn't see some static files in development

Tags: python, django

I am having issues with django not serving some static assets during development.  It's a really strange issue.

This is how the pertinent part of my static directory is right now:

```
site_media
└── static
    ├── css
    │   ├── public.css
    │   ├── site-ada8eab0af.css
```

Now that is my staticfiles directory, and things are correctly imported there from my static directory when I run `manage.py collectstatic`.

I have two lines in my template:

```
<link href="{% static 'css/site-ada8eab0af.css' %}" rel='stylesheet' />
<link href="{% static 'css/public.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

These produce these two lines in the rendered output:

```
<link href="/site_media/static/css/site-ada8eab0af.css" rel='stylesheet' />
<link href="/site_media/static/css/public.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

When I go to the first link, it works fine.  When I go to the public.css link though, I get a 404 error that says `'css/public.css' could not be found`.  The complete link I use is `http://localhost:8000/site_media/static/css/public.css`

What could possibly make it able to serve one of these files, but not the other?

Comment: Try renaming it, off chance that it might be a reserved keyword in Django's internal processing

Comment: The fact that you get a 404 makes this unlikely, but try disabling cache.

Comment: Renaming it didn't do anything, but disabling the cache sure did.  If you want to write that up as an answer there Sahutchi, I will accept it.  Maybe you could explain what would cause that when the file has never existed to be cached before.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your settings

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Django does not serve static files unless you tell it too. (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-development)

Perhaps both links are actually returning 404 and the top link is just cached?

Comment: It already has `urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)` in the settings file.  That is the same thing.